# Getting the eyes of another community in the exchange on a question

Tags: discussion

I've had a few situations where someone asks a well-qualified question on SO but it could still use the eyes of an expert in another domain. **What would be the best way to approach the following situation?**

[This performance improvement question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093740/speeding-up-fourier-related-transform-computations-in-python-opencv/22097606#22097606) could have had some profiling done before it was asked but it is reasonably well presented with working code. I made some trivial optimizations just by looking at it logically but I think real improvement needs to be focused on the more technical part of the code.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897187/locating-the-centroid-center-of-mass-of-spherical-polygons) is another question where it happened. I was eventually able to help but I it took a long time and I have a feeling if a real mathematician looked at it they could have made more useful suggestions.

All I could come up with so far:

1. **Wait** and hope an expert in DSP who also uses python notices it and helps. This seems too luck-dependent and would only work for languages with very large communities)
2. **Post a new question on [DSP Exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)** asking for mathematical improvements with links between each question. This seems ok but it seems like it would be better if everything could be contained in one place. Also, it would need to be rephrased in mathematical terms and might miss some optimizations that could be done by doing things a slightly different way with the libraries that are being used.
3. Join **general DSP chat** and ask for help. I tried this but there is no general DSP chat that I could find.

I look forward to hearing any advice you all have.

Comment: Yes I think this is basically a duplicate of that one. I wasn't able to find it by searching though. I guess because the title of the other is moderator/solution focused while I was searching from the user perspective.

Comment: Yes, it's not very easy to find, but I was engaged in discussion so I was quite sure there are many tips that could solve your issue.

Comment: I don't see any current solutions, but I strongly agree with your proposal. I just posted a comment there. I'll flag this one for duplicate as well if I can.